# How to trigger a change event on a textarea when setting the value via ngModel Binding

Tags: html, angular, binding, textarea

I have a `<textarea>` within a template driven form of an Angular 7 project.
When editing an object, the form is prefilled with the current values. I want to automatically resize the `<textarea>` when the content has changed via the `[(ngModel)]="property"` binding by modifying the element-style.

```
area.style.overflow = 'hidden';
area.style.height = '0';
area.style.height = area.scrollHeight + 'px';
```

The code generally is working, but I cannot find a suitable event to trigger it.
Subscribing to the `change` event of the `<textarea>` is only working on keyboard input. Using `(ngModelChange)="adjustTextAreaSize($event)"` has the same behavior.

I tried to execute my resizing code at the end of the `ngOnInit()` function, but the actual html-control seems to not have any content yet at this point.

Does anyone have an idea which event could do the trick here?
Seemed a rather easy task in the beginning, but I'm breaking my had over this for over an hour now... can not be such a difficult task, can it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> trigger a change event on a textarea when setting the value via ngModel Binding

This will cause infinite triggering if you do so.

If you don't want to monitor the input model change in a more reactive way, a quicker solution (but a bit hacky) will be simply wrap your code inside `setTimeout` in `ngOnInit()` or `ngAfterViewInit()` where you mentioned it was not working.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  updateSize();
});
```

Comment: A bit hacky, yes, but I've become used to it since working with html and JS :) But since I'm calling an asynchronous function in `ngOnInit()` to initiate an API request and one cannot use await there, I had to put the `setTimeout(...)` at the end of this asynchronous function. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is a very simple solution for this.
Wrap your `textarea` inside a `form` and try the code below:-

**HTML**

```
<form #form="ngForm">
   <textarea>....</textarea>
</form>
```

**TS**

```
@ViewChild('form') ngForm: NgForm;
ngOnInit() {
  this.subscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(resp => 
    {
      console.log(resp); // You get your event here
    }
)
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.subscription.unsubscribe();
}
```

Comment: Generally this is working, but the mentioned `<textarea>` already is part of a larger `<form>` and the event is called once for each control of the form. Therefore I've picked the solution from @Xinan But thanks anyway!